# How to insert into a protobuf map in c++?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

For the following Maps unable to insert into the Map

```
map<string, double> doubleProps = 4;
map<string, int32> intProps = 5;
map<string,string> stringProps=6;
```

Here are the following which I have tried , but its not working

```
doubleProps["key"]="value" //doesn't work
*(doubleProps["key"]).insert("value") //doesn't work
doubleProps.insert("key","value")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the way to insert into a map in protobuf object in c++

```
(*mutable_stringprops())["key"]=value
```

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated#map-fields